# JavaScript get Elements By Class Name

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

Why is my code for getElementsByClassName not working? It works when using getElementById but not with a class? I am using the TweenLite extension.

my code that does not work- http://codepen.io/bleubateau/pen/pvbeaO
the same code that works with ID- http://codepen.io/bleubateau/pen/ogLZqb
similar code that does work with the class- http://codepen.io/bleubateau/pen/PwzpQj

```
window.onload = function() {
  var play = document.getElementById("lay");

play.onmouseover = function(){
    TweenMax.to(play, 0.5, {width:"120px", marginLeft:"-60px", marginTop:"-60px", repeat:-1, repeatDelay:0.1, yoyo:true});

};

play.onmouseout = function(){
    TweenLite.to(playBTN, 1, {width:"100px", marginLeft:"-50px", marginTop:"-50px"});
};
}
```

Comment: Remember that when using class name, it returns an array, even when it's a single object ... `document.getElementById("lay")[0]`

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing your HTML - please include it in your question.

Comment: Better to use `document.querySelectorAll('.lay')[0]` as it's more widely supported than *getElementsByClassName*.

Comment: If only the first is wanted, then `.querySelector(".lay")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` generates a node list, so even if your list contained only one item, you would still need to access it like so:

```
var play = document.getElementsByClassName('lay')[0];
```

Comment: Nit: It creates a **`NodeList`**, not an array.

Comment: @FelixKling—not really nit picking, the NodeList is live so may have some unexpected behaviour. ;-)